# PIP can find a specific version from command-line but not from requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install torch v1.5.1, CPU version, as well as torchvision.

Running `pip install torch==1.5.1+cpu torchvision==0.7.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html` runs fine,

but I can't install from a requirements.txt that contains these two lines:

```
torch==1.5.1+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torchvision==0.6.1+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Collecting torch==1.5.1+cpu (from -r /dbfs/databricks/init/echo/requirements.txt (line 9))   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.5.1+cpu (from -r /dbfs/databricks/init/echo/requirements.txt (line 9)) (from versions:
0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2, 0.4.1, 0.4.1.post2, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.1.post2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0) No matching distribution found for torch==1.5.1+cpu (from -r /dbfs/databricks/init/echo/requirements.txt (line 9))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requirements.txt` contains only package versions to install, with syntax described in [PEP440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/). To make it work, rewrite `requirements.txt` as:

```
torch==1.5.1+cpu
torchvision==0.6.1+cpu
```

and then run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Comment: Well pip does not find the right version either. Isn't there a way to specify in the requirements.txt where to find a specific version, like when I'm running `pip install -f`?

Comment: I believe, this is the only way to do it. I've checked my answer rn, it does find `torch 1.5.1+cpu` and corresponding `torchvision`.

Comment: ooooooh, ok, I just ran `pip install -r requirements.txt` without the `-f url` part, now it works! All this time I've been using requirements.txt wrong! Thanks a lot